# Why can't we get the range of a particular negative number

Tags: python, range

```
for i in range(3):
    print (i)
```

We will get the count from 0 to 2.

But I want to know the range of a particular negative number. For example -3.
I came to know from my friend, that because of indexing the negative numbers can't store the value. I am unable to understand this concept, because I am poor in programming language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ranges are not indices, and can produce negative numbers just fine:

```
>>> list(range(-3, 0))
[-3, -2, -1]
```

Do note that I had to specify both a start and end value, otherwise it'll start at 0 and the default direction is to count *up*.

If you need to count down to -3, tell it to count down:

```
>>> list(range(0, -3, -1))
[0, -1, -2]
```

Even so, indexing with negative numbers works just fine too; they count from the end and translate to an absolute index internally that still allow storing:

```
>>> a = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> a[-2] = 'spam'
>>> a
['foo', 'spam', 'baz']
```

Comment: >>> for i in range(-3):
 print i

 
>>>

Comment: @SuryaKumari: That's what I am trying to explain to you: you can't just specify `-3` as the only argument, because that then only specifies the *end value*, and the default start value is `0` and the default step size is `1`. Because `0` is larger than `-3` you are already past the end and nothing is printed. You need to specify different start, end and step values as needed.